# Implementing my own getline function

Tags: c++

Good day,
I'm trying to write a get line function that will take user input and stored it into a character array. The code below is what I've come up with so far but unfortunately my code just sits at the command prompt. I'm not sure what's wrong, I've tried numerous approaches but I can't seem to get it to work. Any help would be appreciated, thank you in advance.

In addition; here's the code for the overloaded function +=;

```
void MyString::operator +=(char addend)
{
    reserve(getLength() + 2);
    char ch[1] = { addend };
    strncat(sequence, ch, 1);
};
```

My getline function:

```
istream& getline(istream& ins, MyString& target)
{

    char ch = 0;
    istream& get(char& ch);
    while (ins && ch != '\n')
    {
        istream& get(char& ch);
        target += ch;
    };
    return ins;
};
```

Comment: You call functions correctly in other parts of your code. What's so different about `get`?

Comment: What do you think `istream& get(char& ch);` is supposed to be doing?

Comment: I thought it polled a individual character from the istream

Comment: No, it actually declares a function. What you should be doing is **calling** the function like this: `ins.get(ch)`.

Comment: But I think the real question is *why* are you performing input like this?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by why?

Comment: Ideally one would create an overload of the extractor for the class. If you need to read a line of input from the stream, use `std::getline()`. You should have an `std::string` data member within the class as well to extract the line into.

Comment: I see, the code I am developing is for a project to create our own string class. My professor explicitly stated not to use the built-in string class.

Comment: @0x499602D2 The whole point of the question is that he can't / doesn't want to use `std::getline()`.

Comment: I guess I could use the get line function, but in the handout he stated:

"For the getline function, you may also want to read one character at a time. You may use the following istream member function get in your program. 
istream& get ( char& c ); // Extracts a character from the
                          // stream and stores it in c."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 istream& get(char& ch);
```

That line will declare a function.  You need to **call** a function:

```
while (ins.get(ch) && ch != '\n')
{
    target += ch;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I got confusing when I was looking up the get function.